# tensorflow nonmaxsuppresion usage

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use nonmax suppresion on my output of CNN.

I am using

```
box = tf.image.non_max_suppression(
    prediction[0],
    [],
    15,
    iou_threshold=0.5,
    name=None
)
```

where `prediction[0]` is 2d array , output of `model.predict`

However printing it outputs

```
Tensor("non_max_suppression/NonMaxSuppressionV2:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32)
```

How to retrieve the coordinations of boxes from the output of `non_max_suppresion`?

Answer (score 0):

This question is asked often in various forms, you should read the writeup here, it all applies to you just the same as it does to that question:

[Working of TensorFlow feature columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49719685/working-of-tensorflow-feature-columns/49720089#49720089)

You should be creating a placeholder for the values your passing into `tf.image.non_max_suppression`

Then you should be calling

```
result_numpy = sess.run(box, feed_dict={placeholder:data})
```

What you printed was the symbolic representation of the math operation you defined, you haven't actually passed anything into tensorflow and asked it to perform the computation yet.