# Working of TensorFlow feature columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow

Say I have a pandas dataframe with column names 'A' and 'B'. If I write the following line :

`col = tensorflow.feature_column.numeric_column('A')`

Does it fetch the values from the dataframe and convert it into a feature column or is `col` a placeholder? I do not understand the working of `tensorflow.feature_column`.

**EDIT**

The code that caused the confusion

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x_data = np.linspace(0.0 , 10.0 , 1000000)
noise = np.random.randn(len(x_data))
b = 9
y_true = (0.5 * x_data) + b
x_df = pd.DataFrame(data = x_data , columns = ['X'])
y_df = pd.DataFrame(data = y_true , columns = ['Y'])
#x_df.head()
my_data = pd.concat([x_df,y_df] , axis = 1
                   )
#my_data.head()
feat_cols = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('q' , shape = [1])]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( x_data, y_true, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns = feat_cols)
input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'q' : x_train} , y_train , batch_size = 8 , num_epochs = None , shuffle = True
                                               )
train_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'q' : x_train} , y_train , batch_size = 8 , num_epochs = 1000 , shuffle = False
                                               )
eval_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'q' : x_test} , y_test , batch_size = 8 , num_epochs = 1000 , shuffle = False
                                               )
```

Comment: The code makes it a lot more clear what's being asked. I understand the question now, but I don't know the answer immediately. I've removed my previous answer.

Comment: Okay. But please get back as soon as you have an answer because I do not think that this question will be getting any more attention :/